# Why is there a peak in drain current

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, circuit-protection, gate-driving

I am simulating the double pulse test to test the working of the Overcurrent pin. Although I like that there is no phase lag between the sense voltage and the OC pin voltage, I am getting this peak in the drain current for all values of DC Bus, L1. Is this got to do with the RC filter values? Changing this does not change this peak very much. Why does this show up?
[image: Circuit]

[image: waveform]

Comment: drain-source capacitance of U16 seems a candidate.

Comment: @Andyaka is it because Cds gets charged very fast as soon as the DC bus voltage is given? Also, how could I decrease it, it's a considerable current peak nearly 2 A ?

Comment: If it is due to MOSFET capacitance it's only reducable by choosing a better MOSFET. It's a common enough phenomena and not usually a problem when using the correct value RC to measure it (or using a blanking circuit if it gives false triggers).

Comment: @Andyaka but it does happen due to Id = Cds x dVbus/dt? If not,could you please explain it a bit?